# Set up a users service, can't post to /auth/local to login

Tags: authentication, feathersjs

I set up a users service for my app with postgres as the DB and Sequelize as the ORM.

Here is my app configuration:

```
app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware)
  .configure(authentication());
```

I can generate a JWT by using `app.authenticate(...)`, and I can validate the user by using `app.authenticate()`.

However, I cannot post to `\auth\local` to login, or `\auth\token`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's does `npm ls feathers-authentication` say?

Comment: Hello @Daff, thanks for taking the time to respond. I get 'Unmet peer dependency Webpack@^1.9.11', trying to add this version of webpack under peer dependencies seemed to overwrite Webpack 2.2.1, which I need for my application as well.

Comment: If you want to use it as documented, `feathers-authentication` has to be version `0.7.x` (not 1.x)